# How do I find a word in all my files in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I'm new to PyCharm (and Python) but can't find a way to do a complete search for a word in all my files in my PyCharm project. Every time I do Edit-->Find it keeps searching either in the current file of searches for the word where my caret is located. How does one do a complete scan of all files for a word that I typed?

When I select Find Usages, it tells me to position my caret to a specific word.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

On the main menu, choose Edit | Find | Find in Path, or press:

Windows or Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> 
Mac: <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

More info [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html)

Comment: My search (Find in Path) stopped working but clicking "File" > "Invalidate Caches/Restart" fixed it.  Just commenting here for anyone else having the same problem.

Comment: Still works in PyCharm 2023.1

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you should try double shift, it's search everywhere.

Comment: This should work according to documentation, but it does not find words in all the files in a project. Ctrl+Shift+F does.

Comment: ... wrong answer. Only searches for particular contexts, not for text in general. "Find in Path" is the answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the "project files" tool window, you can right click a directory and choose "find in path".

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do this. I am using PyCharm 2019.1, but I bet that it will work in previous versions.

### Find in path shortcut:

<kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (mac) or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (windows or linux)

This will open the following in which you can type the word you are looking for.

[image]

### Find action shortcut

<kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (mac) or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (windows or linux)

The following will be opened in which you could type *Find*, and select the option **Find in Path** (notice that the command for this action is displayed next to it). After selecting this, you will be taken to the same menu that is opened when running the *Find in path shortcut*.

[image]

### Right click on your project's directory, and choosing Find in Path...

You can right-click on your project's name, and select the option *Find in Path...* which will also open the menu that is opened after running the Find in Path shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl + Shift + F` as others have stated. In addition, toggle those four buttons below the search bar to vary the scope of your search... `In Project` `Module` `Directory` `Scope`. You really have to watch out. Also, take note of the check boxes above. You want everything to be properly set. You don't want to be searching a Directory when your intention is to search the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you chose the actual working folder, and not it's parent.