# Show usages of module in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a module and am trying to find all the places any method defined in that module is used anywhere outside of it. Is there a function to do this? I'm aware of the call hierarchy tool window, but haven't managed to accomplish this exact use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code: How to find all references of a variable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105741/vs-code-how-to-find-all-references-of-a-variable-in-python)

Comment: Also [How do I find a word in all my files in Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37169123/)

Comment: No, neither of those answer the question. The first one is about VSCode, but I work with PyCharm. The second is at best a workaround with a lot of manual steps involved.

Answer (score 1):

In project view (where you see the file and directory structure), right click on the module you want to check, and click the *Find usages* on context menu.

Because you are using Python, you find where such module is imported (so not really where you use the functions), and from there you can find if the module is used (else the import line will be in gray, or the functions that are not used will be in grey, depending if you are using `import module` or `from module import function1, function2, etc`).

This is not 100% your use case (you will not find directly the function call), but it is powerful enough to get a quick overview.